# Not able select Listview items some times in MAUI for Windows

Tags: c#, maui, maui-windows

We found a strange behavior with ListView some times as we are not able to select some ListView items and those are getting background color as gray as shown in the below Image.

[image]

We are binding Simple ListView and Popping up on a button click, and the strange behavior is it is not happening every time.

If any one encounter with the same problem please let us the workaround for the same.

Comment: Please show some code and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).